# How do I give a unique aria label to the checkboxes for React MUI Datagrid row selection?

Tags: checkbox, material-ui, datagrid, selection, wai-aria

I am trying to make my aria labels unique for each row instead of just the default Select row or unselect row and am not finding a way to do this.

I tried overriding the baseCheckbox in SlotProps but there was no way to match up to row data from the available props passed into baseCheckbox.

Comment: please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask